# Kolmogorov‘s third axiom

Tags: probability-theory

In my notes I have the following note: Kolmogorov‘s 3rd axiom does not apply for  continuous random variables/uncountable events.

The third axiom says that you can add the probability of disjunctive events if they are countable.

So I figured it does not apply with uncountable many events or continuous random variables describing those.

Is that correct, incorrect or ambigious? Can you give me your thoughts about it?

Comment: what is the third axiom? Additivity of the probability measure?

Comment: Yes. It says that you can add the probability of disjunctive events if they are countable. So I figured it does not apply with uncountable many events or continuous random variables describing those. Is that correct?

Comment: So basically it also means that a probability density function just needs fulfill Kolmogorovs two first axioms, not the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to say that Kolmogorov's third axiom does not apply for continuous random variables, since continuous random variables are not probability measures.

However they do of course *induce* probability measures, namely their distribution measure (usually, on $\Bbb R$). **This is always a probability measure** and as such satisfies all of Kolmogorov's axioms automatically. So if anything, your notes are wrong.

In the comments you talk about probability density functions. Again, these don't need to satisfies the Kolmogorov axioms since they are not (candidate) measures! But, they always *induce* probability measures (satisfying the axioms) if you take "probability density function" to mean: "nonnegative measurable function with integral equal to $1$".

It *is* true that the additivity axiom (for countably many disjoint events) does not imply additivity for uncountably many events. For example, let $\lambda$ be the uniform/Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. This satisfies $\sigma$-additivity (it is a measure) but: $$0=\sum_{x\in[0,1]}\lambda(\{x\})\neq\lambda\left(\bigsqcup_{x\in[0,1]}\{x\}\right)=\lambda([0,1])=1$$
So uncountable additivity does not hold.

Comment: Kolmogorov‘s 3rd axiom states: for countable events it holds that…. Since every density function is built by incountable events it means that the axiom does not hold. So there must be some extra 3rd axiom for the case of uncountable events, right?

Comment: @Pippen No, there isn’t. “Since every density function is built by uncountable [uncountably many] events”: what does this mean? Again, density functions are *not* measures but they do create measures, $A\mapsto\int_A f$

Comment: I think I understand. The density function creates probability measures and for these probability measures the third axiom hold as long as these probability measures are based on disjunct countable intervalls. Is this correct?

Comment: @Pippen Mostly correct. A probability measure *always* satisfies the Kolmogorov axioms. The third axiom only refers to countably many disjoint events, the measure itself can be defined on far more events than that. Also it is not true that only intervals are considered, any $\sigma$-algebra containing the intervals on the real line will contain all Borel sets too